# Python: Appending all repeating index values to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want a dictionary that appends ALL indexes as values that have the same key

```
    d = dict()
    population = ['a','b','b','c','d','d']

    for _, m in enumerate(population):
      d[m] = _

    *output*
    {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 5}
```

However, this only outputs the last index found of the keys. I want it to append ALL index values as values to the key. Something like:

```
    {'a': 0, 'b': 1,2 'c': 3, 'd': 4,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the key already exists and append if so. Else add `_` as new value

```
d = dict()
population = ['a','b','b','c','d','d']

for _, m in enumerate(population):
    if m in d:
        d[m] = d[m] +',' + str(_)
    else:
        d[m] = str(_)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': '0', 'b': '1,2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4,5'}
```